# SML curried function which takes a list and a positive number k as inputs and checks whether any element occurs exactly k times in it.

Tags: sml, smlnj

write a curried function f1 which takes a list and a positive number n as inputs
and checks whether any element occurs exactly n times in it.

eg.- f1 [1,2,1,3] 2;
val it = true : bool
- f1 [1,2,1,3] 3;
val it = false : bool

Comment: Show us what you tried already. We don't do homeworks here.

Comment: fun f1(ls,k) = if ls=[] then [] 
ifelse f1(tl(hd(ls))) = [hd(ls)]
 then val i=i+1;
if i=k
then true else false;

Comment: wha tI am trying to do here is I am checking every head of the list and reversing it after each step if two values are same then increment an int by 1 and at the end check that integer to the value k.
If they are equal then return true otherwise false.

Answer (score 0):

You need to count occurrences of each element in your list. You'll need a function which will count occurrences, and a function that will check each element of a list against list itself.

```
fun isThereCeratinNumberOfOccurences(lst, count) =
    let
        fun countOccurences(lst, what) =
            if null lst 
            then 0
            else if hd lst = what
                 then 1 + countOccurences(tl lst,what)
                 else countOccurences(tl lst,what)

        fun checkEachElement(lst, elements, number) =
            if null elements
            then false
            else if countOccurences(lst, hd elements) = count
                 then true
                 else checkEachElement(lst, tl elements, count)
    in 
        checkEachElement(lst, lst, count)
    end
```